# Bousfield class of $TMF$ and $E(2)$

Tags: homotopy-theory, bousfield-localization, topological-modular-form

Let us work concretely at the prime 3. How does $TMF \wedge X \simeq E(2)$ for X a finite type 0 spectrum imply that $TMF$ and $E(2)$ have the same Bousfield class?

Comment: if TMF smashed with Y is zero then so is TMF smashed with X and Y. if E(2) smashed with Y is zero then F smashed with Y is zero for any F in the thick subcategory of E(2). The thick subcategory generated by X contains the sphere so the thick subcategory generated by E(2) contains TMF.

Comment: Ah thanks. The thick category argument was precisely the part I wasn't aware of.